# Moving terminal version of python to homebrew version

Tags: macos, command-line, python

`python -V` shows that I am on 2.7.7 but `brew upgrade python` shows I have 2.7.8 so clearly my terminal isn't looking at the Homebrew version. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Check if `/usr/local/bin` is in your PATH and that it's before `/usr/bin`. In the terminal:

```
echo $PATH
```

I believe `brew doctor` will warn you about this if it's not. Basically, if it's not, the system will look in `/usr/bin` first instead of `/usr/local/bin`, which is where homebrew links everything.

For bash, you just need to add:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

to your `~/.bash_profile` file.

Comment: $ which python returns /usr/local/bin/python so now I'm really confused.

Comment: That's odd, it's definitely not using the system python since that's only version 2.7.5 in Mavericks. Does `ls -l /usr/local/bin/python` point to `../Cellar/python/2.7.8/bin/python` ?

Comment: No its pointing to 2.7.7
How can I make it point to the correct place?

Comment: I just removed 2.7.7 from the Cellar and dealt with it that way...

Comment: Yeah, for some reason it must not have linked properly when you upgraded. `brew unlink python && brew link python` may also have worked.

Comment: @Joe run `brew doctor` to check for any `caveats`. run `brew cleanup` as well.